# Datepicker value into string in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get `datepicker` value into a string or usable format for passing as a parameter to a `get` method. However,
the `get` method i tried always give an error, what is the best way to convert a `datepicker` value into a string?

```html
<div ng-app="getserviceApp" ng-controller="getserviceCtrl">
        <button ng-click="FunctionLoadData()">Load Data</button>

        <input type="date" ng-model="from_date" />
        <input type="date" ng-model="to_date" />
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('getserviceApp', [])

        app.controller('getserviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

            var FromDate = new Date($scope.from_date.selectedDate);
            var ToDate = new Date($scope.from_date.selectedDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some discrepancies in the ng-models and the name of your $scope variables.

In your controller you should have something like

```
   app.controller('getserviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.from_date = new Date();
     $scope.to_date = new Date();

     $scope.loadData = function(){
       console.log($scope.from_date.toISOString().split('T')[0])
       console.log($scope.to_date.toISOString().split('T')[0])
       //prints the dates in yyyy-MM-dd format
     }
   }
```

And in your HTML

```
<div ng-app="getserviceApp" ng-controller="getserviceCtrl">
    <button ng-click="loadData()">Load Data</button>

    <input type="date" ng-model="from_date" />
      value = {{from_date | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}//Display the date
    <input type="date" ng-model="to_date" />
      value = {{from_date | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mistake is `from_date.selectedDate`. Use just model `from_date`

Here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-gqsycu).